# Cannot redirect to another page in PUT request for Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm using Node and Express for the first time to make a simple website that conducts CRUD operations on a database. When I issue my put request I can't get the page to redirect to '/index' and I've run debugger for express and haven't seen anything abnormal, the page simply doesn't change. Any thoughts? Here's the code in server.js

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

app.all('/', function(req,res){
  var cursor = db.collection('jobs').find().toArray(function(err, results) {
     res.render('index.ejs', {jobs: results})
    })
})

app.get('/index',function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
})


app.get('/view',function (req, res) {
    var cursor = db.collection('jobs').find().toArray(function(err, results) {

     res.render('index.ejs', {jobs: results})

    })
})

app.post('/jobs', function(req, res) {
    db.collection('jobs').save(req.body,function(err, result){
    if (err) return console.log(err)

    console.log('saved to database');
    res.redirect('/view');
  })
})

app.put('/view', function(req, res) {
    res.redirect(303, '/index');

})
```

Comment: How are you making the PUT request? How are you testing for the "page to change"?

Comment: I think the problem is http status 303 with PUT. Try to alter to 302 or use nothing.

Comment: @LucasCosta — 302 would be a bad idea, clients are supposed to use the same request method. The OP probably doesn't want the client to make a PUT request to `/`. (I can't see why they would want the client to make one to `/view` instead of `/view/a-specific-thing` either though).

Comment: @Quentin I make the put request in another file called index.ejs using the fetch api. I was able to test that the fetch and put work correctly to update the database record now I'm just trying to test making the current page (/view) reload after the put request goes through. I'm testing by seeing if the page reloads after I submit the button that makes the put request.

Comment: @user2466886 — Why would you expect the page to reload? You are using the fetch API. The point of Ajax is to make an HTTP request from JavaScript *without leaving the page*.

Comment: Oh I see, so if I wanted it to redirect to another page or refresh the current page how could I do that? Or is it not possible?

Comment: @user2466886 — With client side JavaScript. You can't do it via HTTP, that only tells the browser the data it asked for (or where to find that data) not what to do with it when it has it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An HTTP redirect just tells the client to get the data it asked for from somewhere else. It doesn't tell it to treat it any differently.

If you make an Ajax request and get a redirect response, then the browser will follow that redirect silently and return the contents of the new URL to your JavaScript.

The browser **won't** see the redirect and decide to load a new page in the viewport instead of presenting the data to your JavaScript.

If you want to load a new page after making your PUT request, then you need to wait for the response to come in and then (for example) assign a new value to `window.location.href`.